How to handle OutOfOrderSequenceException - Spring Kafka
I have an application which produces and consumes thousands of kafka events. It happens very rarely that OutOfOrderSequenceException is thrown, when KafkaTemplates tries to produce an event to a topic. Unfortunately this is a non-retryable exception (it doesn't extend RetriableExcetpion class, thus the sent action is not retried and the vent is lost.
On the other hand, I can see also in logs, that just before OutOfOrderSequenceExcetion is thrown for let's say an event A, a diffrent exception is also thrown for an event B (they both produce to the same topic). This exception is: NotLeaderOrFollowerException. This one extends RetriableException class and ultimately is sent successfully to a topic (a retry mechanism worked).
Is it safe to catch this exception (OutOfOrderSequenceExcetion) and resent the event with the same KafkaTemplate instance?
My producer config looks as follows:
request.timeout.ms=30000, 
reconnect.backoff.ms=5000,
acks=all,
batch.size=16384, 
retry.backoff.ms=2000,
buffer.memory=33554432,
key.serializer=class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer,
retries=3, 
value.serializer=class io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer,
connections.max.idle.ms=900000, 
max.in.flight.requests.per.connection=1, 
linger.ms=0

